# What Could Cause the Ethernet to not Connect to Internet, Yet Connect to Devices on Network

Tags: network, ssh, ethernet

This has been my problem for about 6 months. On my 2011 MBP, if I connect a working ethernet cable to my ethernet port, it will either do nothing or my internet connection will die totally, even when I'm on a strong wifi network.

More intriguing (frustrating), when I jump on a network connected to a simple switch, I have no internet connection. I.E `ping www.google.com` gets request timeouts or unreachable hosts. But I can run `ifconfig en0 ...`,  then `ssh` into another computer on the network, and from that `ssh` terminal I can connect to the internet no problem. My 'network', by the way, is just my laptop and a desktop connected to a network switch. This happens on multiple switches from different companies.

I've reset everything in Network Preferences, but no help. Has anyone seen this behavior? If so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What, exactly, is the other end oth the eth cable connected to?

Comment: do you use any proxy in your network management ?

Comment: Both computers are connected via ethernet to a network router. I am not using a proxy protocol, but under "Network Preferences -> Ethernet -> Proxies -> Bypass proxy settings for for these hosts and these domains", I have "*.local, 169.254/16" I don't recall adding these, but might have some time in the past

Comment: Hey did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Yes I did. Root cause is unknown. But I created a new ethernet interface in Network Preferences and set that as the default. Seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation yet to add comments above, so I'll put my questions here:

- How does your MBP get the IP address for its ethernet interface?  DHCP?  Manually?
- What is your default router set to (`netstat -rn`)?
- Can you *resolve*, say, google.com (`nslookup www.google.com`)?
- Can you ping any/all the servers mentioned in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

That should help to debug.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. IPV4: DHCP. IPV6: Automatically.      2. Looks like default is set to link#10 Gateway, and netif is bridge0.     3. nslookup failed.      4. All pings had "no rout to host"

Comment: @zachd1_618 If I type `netstat -rn | fgrep default` I get `default  10.1.1.253  UGSc  30  0  en0`, the default router is the second field, 10.1.1.253 in my case.  Can you ping your default router?