# Ethernet says connected but can't access internet

Tags: internet, ethernet

I just got an apple usb to ethernet adaptor, connected it to my internet box and it now says the usb is connected (in system prefs), However I can't access the internet. I get a message that there is no connection when I try a variety of browsers.
Can anyone help me, please?
It is a macbook air 2017 running High Sierra 10.13.6
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Apple.SE! Can you see the IP address in System Preferences? [USB-ethernet-adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317888/apple-usb-ethernet-adapter-has-a-self-assigned-ip-address-and-will-not-be-able-t)... [No ethernet only Wi-Fi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297328/my-mac-wont-connect-with-ethernet-but-will-to-wireless) and [no internet but network devices available](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93099/what-could-cause-the-ethernet-to-not-connect-to-internet-yet-connect-to-devices)

Comment: Hi, yes I can. I changed the ip address manually to the same one as my wifi address. Before doing that it was not showing the green connected signal.

Comment: Is there any login page you are expecting? https://captive.apple.com can find it. also, What do you mean by your Wi-Fi address?

Comment: Changing the IP address manually usually doesn't do what you expect it to do, it especially doesn't automagically make the router (the box you use to access the internet) aware of your Mac. Can you please add a screenshot of the network pane from System Preferences?